# iOS Tab Bar Interface

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitabbarcontroller

I have a login screen for a `UITabBar` application where users are divided into two categories. I want to show a certain tab for one type of user and other tabs for the other type of user. Does anyone have an idea of where to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of my app i have used this code to set **tabbarcontroller** in between app
First create **login** screen without **tabbarcontroller**
This is just a example modify according your condition
define tabbar controller in your **AppDelegate.m**

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.delegate=self;
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=0;
self.tabBarController.delegate=self;


- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
//NSUInteger index=[[tabBarController viewControllers] indexOfObject:viewController];

  // return YES;
}
```

Apply below code where you login and push your controller with tab bar controller

```
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[GeneralViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GeneralViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[MiscQuotationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MiscQuotationController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController4 = [[QuotationListController alloc] initWithNibName:@"QuotationListController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController5 = [[ChargesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChargesViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController7 = [[SalesPartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SalesPartViewController" bundle:nil];

    ///   tab button title
    viewController1.title = @"Basic information";
    viewController2.title = @"Misc Quotation";
    viewController4.title = @"Quotation Line";
    viewController5.title = @"Charges";
    viewController7.title = @"Sales Part Stock";

    // tab button Images
    viewController1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"general.png"];
    viewController2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"misle.png"];
    viewController4.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"history.png"];
    viewController5.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"charges.png"];
    viewController7.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shoebox.png"];

    delegate.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    delegate.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

**// Write your condition of user here**

```
if(user == admin){
delegate.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1,  viewController4, viewController5, viewController7, nil];
}
else{
delegate.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: viewController2, viewController4, viewController5, viewController7, nil];
}
        delegate.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, viewController4, viewController5, viewController7, nil];
        delegate.tabBarController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:delegate.tabBarController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I'd up vote but I don't have enough "experience points" yet I guess.